# way to customize zScore function with r

Tags: r

I am new to R and have a question.
Create a function, zScore, that will take a vector of numbers (x) and converts them to a vector of z-scaled numbers (see code below).  (Don't worry about NA's)

```r
#This creates the z-scaled numbers for sepal lengths
(iris$Sepal.Length - mean(iris$Sepal.Length))/sd(iris$Sepal.Length)
#This creates the z-scaled numbers for sepal widths
(iris$Sepal.Width - mean(iris$Sepal.Width))/sd(iris$Sepal.Width)
```

write a zScore function that is flexible.
thank you for any help you provide

Comment: Do you want `zScore <- function(x) (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)` ? This allows, for example `zScore(iris$Petal.Length)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
# Z-score function
zscore <- function(x) {
  (x - mean(x))/sd(x)
}

library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  mutate(zscore_sepal.length = zscore(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  mutate(zscore_sepal.width = zscore(Sepal.Width))
```

Output:

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species zscore_sepal.length zscore_sepal.width
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa         -1.95660229          -3.514384
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa         -2.15660229          -4.014384
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa         -2.35660229          -3.814384
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa         -2.45660229          -3.914384
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa         -2.05660229          -3.414384
```